# Sort website names alphabetically by the extensions and the name of the website in Java

Tags: java, sorting, web, compareto, alphabetical

I have a .dat file with a list of websites that need to be sorted by the website extension(.com,.edu,.org...etc) alphabetically. It also needs to be sorted by the domain name alphabetically. I have to write a compareTo() method for this. I've already sorted by the extension, so now I just have to sort by the domain name. They are coming into this class from a arraylist in another class

class SiteName implements Comparable

{

```
private String webname;
public SiteName(String n){
    webname=n;
}
public int compareTo(SiteName s){
    int ext1=this.webname.indexOf('.');
    int ext2=s.webname.indexOf('.');        
    if (this.webname.charAt(ext1+1)>s.webname.charAt(ext2+1))
        return 1;
    else return -1;



}
public String toString(){
    return webname;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use the indexes from `indexOf()` to substring the extension, then compare extensions. If extensions are the same, compare full site name:

```
public int compareTo(SiteName that) {
    int cmp = this.getWebnameExt().compareTo(that.getWebnameExt());
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = this.webname.compareTo(that.webname);
    return cmp;
}
private String getWebnameExt() {
    int idx = this.webname.indexOf('.');
    return (idx == -1 ? "" : this.webname.substring(idx));
}
```

For performance, you may want to cache the extension.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help so much!